# Action of webform displayed in modal opened by OpenModalDialogCommand in AjaxResponse

Tags: webforms, ajax, modal-dialogs

I'm trying to open a webform in a modal by using `OpenModalDialogCommand` in an `AjaxResponse` like this.

- in `buildForm` method, I'm specifying AJAX callback like this:

```
$form['actions']['submit'] = [
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => $this->t('Send'),
  '#ajax' => [
    'callback' => [$form_state->getFormObject(), 'ajaxSubmitForm'],
    'disable-refocus' => TRUE,
    'progress' => 'none',
  ],
];
```

- in `ajaxSubmitForm`, I'm specifying `AjaxResponse` like this:

```
$output['webform'] = [
  '#type' => 'webform',
  '#webform' => 'contact',
  '#default_data' => [],
];
$response->addCommand(new OpenModalDialogCommand(
  'My title',
  $output,
  [
    'width' => '600px',
    'dialogClass' => 'social-dialog--task-webform',
  ]
));
return $response;
```

This works fine, but the `action` attribute of the `<form>` rendered in the modal is set to the path of the page, instead of the webform. Which results in HTML being returned in the AJAX response and the `Drupal.AjaxError` in the browser console. How can I fix this?

EDIT: I noticed, that `views_ui` core module defines a [SetFormCommand](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views_ui%21src%21Ajax%21SetFormCommand.php/class/SetFormCommand/), which allows for custom URL used when views form is displayed in the modal. Isn't something like this also needed for webform forms?

EDIT 2: So I tried to reimplement `SetFormCommand` for webform, but it's not working. Perhaps I'm limited by my insufficient knowledge of AJAX API in Drupal here.

Comment: I haven't used `OpenModalDialogCommand` yet but found this [link](https://gist.github.com/edwardchan/2c2d4f8b340f1425a4902c05afa7ecc6) check once .. hope will be helpful.

Comment: forget to add forum link too .. check [solution](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2019-12-20/modal-dialog-form-not-reacting-to).

Comment: Thanks @Lokesh1024, this are indeed helpful resource, but none of them is a webform-specific - which is what I need.